# 'Use' namespace doesn't do anything - PHP

Tags: php, namespaces, psr-4

So i've got the following code, but for some reason the `use` statement doesn't seem to do anything.

```
class Image {
    use \App\Traits\File;

    public static function get()
    {
         $image_url = File::getVersion()
    }
}
```

Throws an error `Uncaught Error: Class 'File' not found`. But it works if I change it to `$image_url = \App\Traits\File::getVersion()`.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of that I would have created `Traits` directory in `Http` folder. Inside that I created file `File`.  in class,

```
use App\Http\Traits\File;
class Image {
    use File;
    public static function get()
    {
         $image_url = File::getVersion()
    }
}
```

Above this should be the proper syntax to use namespace and trait.

Comment: Thanks I moved the `use` statement outside the class and that worked. Could you explain the reasoning for the `Http` folder though?

Comment: I can say it's a laravel default folder structure.

Comment: Anyway you got your solution. I able to give you answer comparing with laravel. :)